# Does $A_1\supset A_2 \supset \cdots $ imply $\bigcap A_n \neq \emptyset$?

Tags: general-topology

given a countable collecstion of sets $\{A_n\}$ which satisfies
$$A_1\supset A_2 \supset \cdots \supset A_n\supset \cdots $$

My intuition is
$$
\bigcap A_n  \neq \emptyset
$$
Please show me a counter-example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$A_n = (0, \frac1n) \subseteq \Bbb R$ is a counterexample.

Answer (score 4):

$A_n = \{n, n+1, n+2, \cdots\}$ is a counter-example.